# UnknownHostException while accessing HTTPS url using jsoup

Tags: java, https, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse and manipulate HTML using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It is working perfectly fine for HTTP URLs but it's throwing `UnknownHostException` if a HTTPS URL is used. Following is my code:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/").get();
```

I was rather expecting an exception related to SSL certificates but what could be the reason for `UnknownHostException`? Please note that the following code runs perfectly for http://www.google.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), you need to specify the proxy for https in a seperate way.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "your host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "your port");
```

Comment: are you sure? Because while working with HTTPConnections I never changed them explicitly for https urls.

Comment: Well from personal experience and from the linked documentation I'd say yes. Maybe in other projects the HTTP/HTTPS proxies were set universally, or added at runtime?

Comment: btw specifying these properties in standalone java application throws   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory. Any idea why is it referring to these files ?

Comment: Mostly guesswork, but it looks like your program tries to establish a HTTPS connection and therefor tries to call the servers default sslsocketfactory (to do the handshake). This fails though. Could be a configuration problem, could be a classpath problem.

Comment: +1 Yes, it was a classpath problem. Thanks a lot, it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps you.
I am using JSoup.  consider this sample website,

String url = https://trickideas.com;

Jsoup.connect(url).get();

I get unknown host Exception if i try to connect to 
https://www.trickideas.com/

I don't get unknown host exception if i connect to https://trickideas.com/

I meddled with SSL certificates thinking that can be issue, but it wasn't. Issue was a simple typo.

Just check, if this is the issue.